# How to create custom menu with 3 buttons at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uibutton

I would like to create some kind of menu with 3 buttons at the bottom of my screen. How should i approach this, with 3 buttons next to each other that have some transparent space at the top?

Any better way?

[image]

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: while adding the white dot to the screenshot in an image manipulation program, why didnt you scale it to be smaller?

Comment: I tried changing images for segmented control, but they are all of the same size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow below 4 steps

1) Need to get 4 image for this (3 button image and 1 background image with pattern and transparent gradient)

2) Create `UIView`

3) set `UIView` with background image (pattern and transparent gradient)

4) add three button to subview of `UIView`.

you can do this on IB or you can create custom `UIView`